# Windows Phone 8 , how to share code,xmal,asset between multiple projects

Tags: windows-phone-8

Now I have **AppA** finished. but I want to make **AppB,AppC**. and **AppB,AppC** share most of the code in **AppA**(including xaml, asset, code,etc.). only a few changes for the **AppB,AppC** respectively.I mean, the 3 apps can be installed on the same windows phone separately with different icons.

Does anybody know how to build **AppB,AppC** referring **AppA** in code? 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Either extract as much as you can in a shared/common project or use "Add as Link" to include files from AppA into AppB and AppC. 
Note that XAML files don't support conditional compilation so they must be identical for all projects in order to link them. You can potentially extract XAML differences into App.xaml StaticResources (identical keys) in order to make them identical and link them. 
Sharing XAML is very reasonable when targeting the same platform. 
You can also link cs files even if they are similar (few changes) by using conditional compilation. 
Partial classes can also spare you the conditional compilation ceremony in many cases.
Finally Resource files are very good candidate for reuse. If you decide to put them on a shared library remember to wrap the generated Resource class in another public one with a public constructor shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd882554%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) in order to avoid the internal constructor issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all your code in an external class library. As far as I know though your assets and pages need to exist in each project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share code and assets between multiple assemblies, you can create a class library for Windows Phone and put all the code inside it. When you need to use that library, simply link it in your target applications.

When you want to navigate to a page in your library, use the following syntax:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/AssemblyName;component/page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```